# Make 2 rasters same dimensions for gdal_calc

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have a single and multi beam dataset which I am trying to use gdal_calc on in Python 3.8

At present, I am getting below error:

`Error! Dimensions of file C:........tif 250, 290) are different from other files (250, 461).  Cannot proceed`

How can I make the 2 rasters compatible for gdals calculations?

Comment: [Warp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) them to the same extent and resolution

Comment: @BERA I have tried using the same extent and resolution for both but I am still getting different dimensions. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add basic info about the image size, pixel size, and extents that your source images have now after warping.